# Only display content that belongs to User in admin/content

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I have a role called **Content Editor** and 2 users **Chang** and **Liang** with that same role.

They can both *add/edit* their own content. The role permission is set in such a way that they can only edit own content.

However, when **Chang** navigates to `/admin/content`, this user can see all the contents written by all the users.

How to restrict Chang so that he can see only the contents he has written when visiting the `/admin/content` link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sandbox-module for that called [Content Admin Access](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/stijnstroobants/2316745)
Maybe this is what you are looking for.

> With Content Admin Access you can set permissions to show or hide others content in the admin/content overview.
>
> Enabling this module will by default show only your own content in the admin/content overview.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that with "*see all the contents*" you mean "can browse the actual content" (and not something like "the list of nodes with their titles").

In that case, you might consider using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module. Basically your rule would look like something like this:

- **Event**: Content is viewed
- **Condition**: (User has role = Content Editor) AND (node:author not equal to site:current-user)
- **Action**: Page redirect (to some appropriate node that seems appropriate)

Answer (score 0):

Install [Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views).

> Replaces administrative overview/listing pages with actual views for
>   superior usability.

You can then alter the view that displays node listing to include content by currently logged in user etc.

Comment: yes thanks, BUT it restricts the content for Admin user as well. eg: **user1** should see all the contents in the list but with this approach even for **user1** it shows only the contents the user created

Comment: Implement [hook_views_pre_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view/7) where you add the user id as an arg, except if user is admin. Remove the default 'from logged in user' bit in the views contextual filter and if not present then view all.

Answer (score 0):

We can use hook_query_TAG_alter to filter content at admin/content page

```
/**
 * Implement hook_query_TAG_alter()
 * Need to filter out nodes from admin/content page.
 */
function hook_query_node_admin_filter_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  global $user;
  if ($query->hasTag('node_admin_filter')) {
    $query->condition('uid', $user->uid);
  }
}
```

We can bypass super admin by adding condition.

Thanks,
Devendra